# JPA inheritance query (Eclipse Link)

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

Consider the following schema:

```java
public class A {
    @Id
    int id;
    String fieldA;
}
```

```java
public class B extends A {
    String fieldB;
}
```

```java
public class C extends A {
    String fieldC;
}
```

How can I query `A` in such a way to get ***all*** the `C`'s and get ***only*** the `B`'s where `fieldB="someValue"`?

I have tried to use **treat** in order to make downcast but it seems that the filter on `B` is working on all the parent class (`A`).

Is such query possible in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a query with the 'type' keyword to filter by type and an exists subquery to filter the C entities:

```
select a
from A a
where type(a) = :type
or exists (
  select 1
  from B b
  where b.id = a.id
  and b.fieldB = :fieldB
)
```

The class type of entity C is passed by invoking the setParameter method of the query instance.

Comment: You should use OR instead of AND for the exists clause.

Comment: yeah i have solved this problem using similer approach, but is there a build in command to solve it. actually i have 5 class inherit the main class and i am making 2 - 3 filter in each subclass . using or with the type lead me to a monster query (that will effect performance for sure)